# Insert data from Android app to SQL server database using Web Services

Tags: c#, android, .net, sql-server, web-services

I have an Android code that returns a JSONArray in the form [{"key0":"john","key2":"ann","key1":"joe"}]. I have a method that displays the above names in the list for eg. "john" , "ann" in a  CustomListView using checkboxes. I also have a method that I used to check or tick the values . I now need to insert these checked values in my SQL Server database using a web service . I am working on localhost.

Can any one tell me how to create a web service in .NET using C# to insert data into a SQL Server database ?

Here is my [Android code](http://pastebin.com/epNKw5cc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link for you : [Introduction to Building Windows Communication Foundation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480190.aspx)

I recommend you to build WCF service just go through link you will get idea how to build it.

Comment: Thanks for the link !! I am very new to WCF to be honest.I would prefer SOAP web service because Android has a ksoap library that I can make use of . SO u knw how to do it using SOAP web service ?

Comment: @Parth_90 - i suggest you to google it out you find lot of article and tutorial for that